# Truly parallel processing

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I want to run 7 threads\tasks parallelly in C#. Out of the 7 threads I want the result of 1st thread in the list within a certain timeout lets say 200ms **(it is not necessary for the first thread to finish first, it is just that if it fails or takes more than the required amount of time then, I don't need to wait for any other tasks to complete)**. If I don't get the result of the first thread in the list within 200ms or if the result is null\invalid then, I would like to abort or cancel all tasks. If the result from the first thread is within the timeout and is valid I would like to see if any of the other tasks have completed and given a valid result. If yes then I would like to take the result and cancel\terminate all the remaining tasks. The code that I have come up with using Task class is as follows:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TaskWrapper _taskWrapper = new TaskWrapper();
        Stopwatch _st = new Stopwatch();
        _st.Start();
        ThreadObject t = await _taskWrapper.DoTasks();
        _st.Stop();
        if (t != null)
        {
            txtResult.Text += t._id.ToString() + " and " + t._idSec
                + " is completed in " + _st.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms."
                + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        else
        {
            txtResult.Text += "All failed in " + _st.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms."
                + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        //_taskWrapper = null;
        //_taskWrapper.Dispose();
    }
}

public class TaskWrapper
{
    Task<ThreadObject> _t1;
    Task<ThreadObject> _t2;
    Task<ThreadObject> _t3;
    Task<ThreadObject> _t4;
    Task<ThreadObject> _t5;
    Task<ThreadObject> _t6;
    Task<ThreadObject> _t7;

    ThreadObject _tO1;
    ThreadObject _tO2;
    ThreadObject _tO3;
    ThreadObject _tO4;
    ThreadObject _tO5;
    ThreadObject _tO6;
    ThreadObject _tO7;

    public async Task<ThreadObject> DoTasks()
    {
        var _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken _cancellationToken = _cancellationTokenSource.Token;

        //_cancellationToken.Register(() => { this.Dispose(); });

        _tO1 = new ThreadObject(1);
        _t1 = new Task<ThreadObject>(() => _tO1.DoAction(50), _cancellationToken);

        _tO2 = new ThreadObject(2);
        _t2 = new Task<ThreadObject>(() => _tO2.DoAction(10), _cancellationToken);

        _tO3 = new ThreadObject(3);
        _t3 = new Task<ThreadObject>(() => _tO3.DoAction(30), _cancellationToken);

        _tO4 = new ThreadObject(4);
        _t4 = new Task<ThreadObject>(() => _tO4.DoAction(40), _cancellationToken);

        _tO5 = new ThreadObject(5);
        _t5 = new Task<ThreadObject>(() => _tO5.DoAction(60), _cancellationToken);

        _tO6 = new ThreadObject(6);
        _t6 = new Task<ThreadObject>(() => _tO6.DoAction(70), _cancellationToken);

        _tO7 = new ThreadObject(7);
        _t7 = new Task<ThreadObject>(() => _tO7.DoAction(200), _cancellationToken);

        var _tasks = new List<Task<ThreadObject>> { _t1, _t2, _t3, _t4, _t5, _t6, _t7,
            new Task<ThreadObject>(() => { Thread.Sleep(1); return null; }) };

        var _completedTasks = new List<Task<ThreadObject>>();

        var _mainTask = new List<Task<ThreadObject>>();

        _tasks.AsParallel().WithCancellation(_cancellationToken).ForAll(o => o.Start());
        while (_tasks.Count > 0)
        {
            var completed = await Task.WhenAny(_tasks);
            if (completed.Result._isComplete)
            {
                if (completed.Result._id == 1)
                {
                    _mainTask.Add(completed);
                }
                else
                {
                    _completedTasks.Add(completed);
                }
                if (_completedTasks.Count > 0 && _mainTask.Count > 0)
                {
                    _mainTask[0].Result._idSec = _completedTasks[0].Result._id;
                    _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
                    return await _mainTask[0];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _tasks.Remove(completed);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public class ThreadObject
{
    public bool _isComplete = false;
    public int _id;
    public int _idSec;

    private Thread thread;
    //private static readonly object lockObj;
    public ThreadObject(int id)
    {
        _id = id;
    }
    public ThreadObject DoAction(int _milliseconds)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(_milliseconds);
        _isComplete = true;
        File.AppendAllText("E:\\ThreadingDemo2_" + _id + ".txt",
            DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff") + " " + _id
                + " Processing finished." + Environment.NewLine);
        return this;
    }
}
```

I am unsure as to how to implement the timeout logic in the above mentioned approach. Therefore I implemented another logic using `Thread` class to achieve the same as follows:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadWrapper threadWrapper = new ThreadWrapper();
        Stopwatch _st = new Stopwatch();
        _st.Start();
        ThreadObject TO = threadWrapper.DoTasks();
        _st.Stop();
        if (TO != null)
        {
            if (TO._idSec == 0)
                txtResult.Text += TO._id.ToString() + " is completed in "
                    + _st.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms." + Environment.NewLine;
            else
                txtResult.Text += TO._id.ToString() + " and " + TO._idSec
                    + " is completed in " + _st.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms."
                    + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        else
        {
            txtResult.Text += "All failed in " + _st.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms."
                + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
}

public class ThreadWrapper
{
    Thread _t1;
    Thread _t2;
    Thread _t3;
    Thread _t4;
    Thread _t5;
    Thread _t6;
    Thread _t7;

    ThreadObject _tO1;
    ThreadObject _tO2;
    ThreadObject _tO3;
    ThreadObject _tO4;
    ThreadObject _tO5;
    ThreadObject _tO6;
    ThreadObject _tO7;

    ThreadObject mainThread;
    int SecId = 0;

    public ThreadObject DoTasks()
    {
        _tO1 = new ThreadObject(1);
        //_tO1.TaskCompleted += TaskCompleted;
        _t1 = new Thread(() => mainThread = _tO1.DoAction(50));

        _tO2 = new ThreadObject(2);
        _tO2.TaskCompleted += TaskCompleted;
        _t2 = new Thread(() => _tO2.DoAction(10));

        _tO3 = new ThreadObject(3);
        _tO3.TaskCompleted += TaskCompleted;
        _t3 = new Thread(() => _tO3.DoAction(30));

        _tO4 = new ThreadObject(4);
        _tO4.TaskCompleted += TaskCompleted;
        _t4 = new Thread(() => _tO4.DoAction(40));

        _tO5 = new ThreadObject(5);
        _tO5.TaskCompleted += TaskCompleted;
        _t5 = new Thread(() => _tO5.DoAction(60));

        _tO6 = new ThreadObject(6);
        _tO6.TaskCompleted += TaskCompleted;
        _t6 = new Thread(() => _tO6.DoAction(70));

        _tO7 = new ThreadObject(7);
        _tO7.TaskCompleted += TaskCompleted;
        _t7 = new Thread(() => _tO7.DoAction(20));

        List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread> { _t1, _t2, _t3, _t4, _t5, _t6, _t7 };

        threads.AsParallel<Thread>().ForAll<Thread>(o => o.Start());

        _t1.Join(200);

        Task.Run(() =>
        threads.AsParallel<Thread>().ForAll<Thread>(o => o.Abort()));
        if (mainThread != null)
        {
            mainThread._idSec = SecId;
        }

        return mainThread;
    }

    private void TaskCompleted(int id, int idSec, bool isCompleted)
    {
        if (SecId == 0)
            SecId = id;
    }
}

public class ThreadObject
{
    public bool _isComplete = false;
    public int _id;
    public int _idSec;
    public delegate void NotifyTaskCompletion(int id, int idSec, bool isCompleted);
    public event NotifyTaskCompletion TaskCompleted;

    private static readonly object lockObj = 1;
    //private static readonly object lockObj;
    public ThreadObject(int id)
    {
        _id = id;
    }
    public ThreadObject DoAction(int _milliseconds)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(_milliseconds);
        _isComplete = true;
        //lock (lockObj)
        //{
        //    File.AppendAllText("E:\\ThreadingDemo3_" + _id + ".txt"
        //        , DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff") + " " + _id
        //            + " Processing finished." + Environment.NewLine);
        //}
        TaskCompleted?.Invoke(_id, _idSec, _isComplete);
        return this;
    }
}
```

I was using `Parallel.Invoke` method previously to execute the tasks parallelly but recently it has come to my attention that `Parallel.Invoke` does not actually process tasks parallelly and hence ends up taking up more time than necessary.
Now to my actual questions, yes there are multiple, as follows:

1. Is there any way to add a timeout in my parallel tasks? I already know one way in which I can add a Task in the collection of tasks that I am running parallelly which would be suspended for 200ms or whatever timeout I want and then return null. (Since I am using `WhenAny` to check for completion, control will be returned to the calling UI thread). But that feels like cheating to me, so I want to know if there is any other approach.
2. When I am creating a `Task` from a class in this case `TaskWrapper` will disposing or setting the `TaskWrapper` object to null abort or destroy the Tasks created\running using that object?
3. Similarly, for threads, if I have created a thread\threads from inside a class in this case `ThreadWrapper`, will disposing or setting the `ThreadWrapper` object to null abort or destroy the threads created\running using that object?

Edited: To clear the confusion mentioned in comment.

Comment: This question is a little confusing, if a first thread finishes first, why are there are threads that have finished.

Comment: It is not necessary that the first thread will finish first. But if it does not finish in a said time I do not require any of the results from any of the threads. That is part of the logic that I need to implement.

Comment: The first task, is that a specific one or just the first of the list that is able to finish in 200ms?

Comment: The first specific thread. Edited the post to reflect the same.

Comment: @AnuragPatil tasks aren't threads and don't need wrappers. .NET already offers several higher-level abstractions for data parallelism, concurrency, pipeline processing etc. You can use `Parallel.ForEach` or `PLINQ` to process a large amount of data in parallel using all available cores. You can use the Dataflow classes to construct processing pipelines with varying degrees of parallelism per block. All classes support cancellation out of the box. So what are you trying to do?

Comment: @AnuragPatil what is the *actual* problem? The entire question is confusing and the code doesn't help at all, because it tries to reinvent tasks - it tries to create wrappers over threads, even though *tasks* work in that way. Managing threads is the job of the TaskScheduler, there's no need to manually handle threads

Comment: *"I would like to abort or cancel all tasks"* <== The `DoAction` in your example in not cancelable. It does not accept a `CancellationToken` parameter. As a result it cannot be canceled. The cancellation in .NET is [cooperative](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads). Are your real methods also like that?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Hi, what I am trying to achieve is as follows:
1) I have to take input from 7 cameras which are going to be triggered simultaneously and decode the images.
2) The design of the system is such that if the decoded value from Camera 1 is null then I need not worry about the rest of the cameras.
3) This should happen each time the cameras are triggered.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way would be a cancellationToken that cancels after 200ms using the [CancelAfter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.cancelafter?view=net-5.0) method. Another option would be run `await Task.Delay(200)`. I would also recommend using `Parallel.For` since this would be much more compact code:

```
    public static void CancelParallel()
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(200));
        var po = new ParallelOptions()
        {
            CancellationToken = cts.Token
        };
        void ParallelMethod(int iterationIndex, ParallelLoopState state)
        {
            // Do whatever
            // if the iteration is long running you can check if it should exit
            if (state.ShouldExitCurrentIteration)
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        var loopResult = Parallel.For(0, 7, po, ParallelMethod);
        if (loopResult.IsCompleted)
        {
            // Do something if all threads completed
        }
        else
        {
            // Do something else
        }
    }
```

If you only care about the success of the first iteration, set some flag if this succeeds and check that instead of the loopResult.

Note that Parallel.For will stop running new iterations when the token is canceled, but will let existing iterations run to completion, so you might or might not want to check the token inside the iteration

Comment: Checking the `po.CancellationToken` inside the parallel loop is probably redundant. The `Parallel.For` implementation is supposed to watch the token, and propagate an `OperationCanceledException` if the token is signaled. If you want to exit early so that a single long-running operation don't delay needlessly the completion of the `Parallel.For`, the property to query is probably the [`ParallelLoopState.ShouldExitCurrentIteration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate.shouldexitcurrentiteration).

Comment: The intent was to demonstrate how to cancel a long running loop iteration. Checking the `po.CancellationToken` is copied from [how to cancel a parallel loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-cancel-a-parallel-for-or-foreach-loop)

Comment: I don't like the example in the docs. Please check out [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pQIUcU) fiddle. The `Parallel.For` is canceled automatically when the token is canceled.